# Can A StyleSheet and Schema be combined into a single XSD file?

Tags: xml, xslt, schema, declaration

Fellow Forum Members,

From what I know about XML the Schema defines the structure rules and the StyleSheet drives how the formatting for the PDF output is done. However, does the following question have a correct or incorrect answer to it, "Can both a Schema and Stylesheet be combined into a single XSD file?"

The reason I'm asking this is because of the code below:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><!DOCTYPE dmodule[
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/ent/ISOEntities" > %ISOEntities;
]><dmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/xml_schema_master/procedSchema.xsd"`

The XML code shown above is from a data module that conforms to the S1000 D standard. It resides inside what is known as Common Source Data Base (CSDB). The last line in the code indicates the Schema (xsd file) that is being utilized. However, what seems to be missing is any code that shows what Stylesheet is being used.

Therefore, my guess now is the the XSD file contains both the Schema and Stylesheet within a single XSD file. Is this possible? Is it allowed in the XML world two have both in a single file?

If this is not possible can someone clarify for me why a StyleSheet declaration is missing following the XML Declaration located on row 1 of the code shown above?

Am I correct to think that it's a required XML rule to have a StyleSheet declaration embedded within the data module itself?  Or can a StyleSheet Declaration be controlled externally by the CSDB?  My thinking has always been that all Stylesheet Declarations need to be hard coded into the data module itself.  Otherwise, the Parser does not know what Stylesheet to use. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that the stylesheet needs to be referenced from the source document is quite incorrect. That would mean the source document could only be processed using one stylesheet, which would completely defeat the purpose! Generally a transformation is invoked by specifying both the source document and the stylesheet. It's possible to reference a stylesheet from a source document, but this is by no means invariable practice.

Therefore your conclusion that the stylesheet must be bundled with the schema is also incorrect.

In fact, referencing the schema from the source document is also somewhat questionable practice. If you want to validate the document, that means you don't trust it, and if you don't trust it, why should you trust it to reference the right schema?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, YES an XSD schema and the XSL stylesheet can be defined in the same file, thusly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:import-schema>
    <xs:schema>
      <xs:element name="items">
        <xs:complexType>      
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                 <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                 <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                 <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
               </xs:sequence>
               <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
               <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>      
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
  </xsl:import-schema>

  <xsl:template match="/PurchaseOrder">
    <items xsl:validation="strict">
      <xsl:copy-of select="item[price < 15]" />
    </items>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But not all XSL engines support "import-schema," so your mileage may vary.

The slightly longer answer is that a schema can validate the input before transformation, OR the output after transformation. Your implementation will depend on which you're interested in doing.
More information to be found here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-schemaxslt/index.html